# StatsModels Groupby linear regression data type error: Pandas data cast to numpy dtype of object. Check input data with np.asarray(data)

Tags: python, pandas, statsmodels

I am trying to run linear regression by group using statsmodels, but I'm getting the error: Pandas data cast to numpy dtype of object. Check input data with np.asarray(data).

Dtypes are the following: EmailCampaignId: int64, percentOpen: float64, and Email Dates: datetime64[ns].

```
import statsmodels.api as sm 

def GroupRegress(data, yvar, xvars):
    Y = np.asarray(data[yvar])
    X = data[xvars]
    X['intercept'] = 1.
    result = sm.OLS(Y, X).fit()
    return result.params

df_emails.groupby('EmailCampaignId').apply(GroupRegress, 'percentOpen', ['Email Dates'])
```

I believe int64 and float64 should be okay, and maybe regressing on datatime64 is the issue. I'd appreciate any help!

Additionally, I'd like to output R^2 for each group in a table. How do I pull this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the problem is in the `datetime` type.  if you intend to use dates as a continuous predictor (i.e., as interval data), you can convert that column to `int` or `float`, which will treat it as number of days/hours/minutes/seconds or some other increment since Jan 1, 1970, for example:

```
pd.to_datetime('1970-01-02').value
# 86400000000000 nanoseconds since 1/1/70
```

For R-squared, the edit to the `return` statement in the function below will output those values as an extra column in the final dataframe.

So,

```
# convert date column from datetime to number of days since 1/1/70
df_emails['Email Dates'] = df_emails['Email Dates'].apply(
    lambda x: x.value / (1e9 * 24 * 3600)
)

def GroupRegress(data, yvar, xvars):
    Y = np.asarray(data[yvar])
    X = data[xvars]
    X['intercept'] = 1.
    result = sm.OLS(Y, X).fit()
    return result.params.append(
        pd.Series([result.rsquared], index=['r_squared'])
    )

res = df_emails.groupby('EmailCampaignId').apply(
    GroupRegress, 'percentOpen', ['Email Dates']
)
# res will look like:
#                    Email Dates       intercept    r_squared
# EmailCampaignId           
#              0            xxxx            xxxx         xxxx
#              1            xxxx            xxxx         xxxx
```